# Jquery error message isn't displaying

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I want an error message to appear when I leave the booking reference field blank. However, instead of the error message appearing the input field is disappearing when I use the keyup change function. I need to use this function and I need to include add and remove classes. Not sure what is wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ref").on('keyup change', function(event) {
    if ($('#ref').val() == '') {
      $("#ref").addClass("errorMsg");
      $("#search").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $("#ref").removeClass("errorMsg");
      $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.errorMsg {
  display: none;
  color: #FEA04D;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> <span class="errorMsg">Reference number 
     required</span>
  <button type="button" id="search" disabled>Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: add your CSS also

Comment: You are also missing an closing tag for your `input`

Comment: maybe display:none ? that's hiding the input . So what do you actually want to hide when the error msg appears /

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `errorMsg` class on input  that's why it's hiding. You need to toggle display of error class like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ref").on('keyup change', function(event) {
    if ($('#ref').val() == '') {
      $(".errorMsg").css("display", "block");
      $("#search").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $(".errorMsg").css("display", "none");
      $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.errorMsg {
  display: none;
  color: #FEA04D;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> <span class="errorMsg">Reference number 
     required</span>
  <button type="button" id="search" disabled>Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding/removing the errorMsg class to the input box rather than hiding/showing the error message that has the class errorMsg

https://jsfiddle.net/eqyy77q7/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#ref").on('keyup change', function(event) {
if ($(this).val() == '') {
$(".errorMsg").show();
$(this).addClass("error");
$("#search").attr('disabled','disabled');
} else {
    $(".errorMsg").hide();
    $(this).removeClass("error");
    $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
}  }) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in the logic for showing and hiding the error message span element, instead you are hiding the input.

A simple solution to this is to think about what you are actually doing.

`$("#ref").addClass("errorMsg");` Here you add a class to the element with an ID of `ref`. What you want to do is to show or hide the span element containing the error message depending on the input value. You want this to be triggered on the events keyup and change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ref").on('keyup change', function(event) {
  $('#ref').val().length < 1 ? disableInput() : enableInput();
  });
  
  function enableInput() {
   $('.errorMsg').hide();
    $("#errorMsg").removeClass('hasError');
    $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  
  function disableInput() {
   $('.errorMsg').show();
    if (!$("#errorMsg").hasClass('hasError')) {
     $("#errorMsg").addClass('hasError');
    }
    $("#search").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.errorMsg {
  display:none;
  color: #FEA04D;
  font-size:14px;
}
.errorMsg.hasError {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
 <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
 <br>
 <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number"
 placeholder="12" required>
 <span class="errorMsg hasError">Reference number 
 required</span>
 <button type="button" id="search" disabled>Search</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i need to use addClass and removeClass as it is for an assignment

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

**CSS:**

```
.msg{
  display: none;
}
.errorMsg {
display: inline-block;
color: #FEA04D;
font-size:14px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ref").on("blur keyup change", function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).next().addClass("errorMsg");
      $("#search").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      $(this).next().removeClass("errorMsg");
      $("#search").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

**Here is preview link:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/QObqKq

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't look good, You don't have a class errorMsg for #ref. Pls redo your classes

```
$("#ref").removeClass("errorMsg");
```

Comment: I have a span class though

Comment: That's not the way it works. Was I down-voted because I did not provide a full working code :)))